# LOGON триггер: запрет подключения

Tags: sql-server

Необходимо в триггере запретить подключаться к базе данных пользователям без прав суперадминистратора в нерабочее время, вызывая ошибку внутри тела триггера.
Как можно сделать так, чтобы ошибка вызывалась внутри триггера? Если через try...catch, то как?

```sql
GO  
CREATE TRIGGER connection_trigger
ON ALL SERVER
FOR LOGON  
AS  
BEGIN  
IF IS_SRVROLEMEMBER ('sysadmin')=0 OR           
    DATEPART(year, GETDATE())=6 OR DATEPART(year, GETDATE())=7 OR
    DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE())>=18 OR DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE())<9 OR DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE())=13
    ROLLBACK;  
ELSE
    print('Вы успешно зашли на сервер!')
END;
```

Comment: THROW 51000, 'User not admin.', 1;

Comment: DATEPART(year, GETDATE())=6 OR DATEPART(year, GETDATE())=7 => DATEPART(year, GETDATE()) IN (6, 7)

Comment: DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE()) >=18 OR DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE())<9 => DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE()) NOT BETWEEN 8 AND 18